# Ext Js error when using ext-gen (caractere incorrect)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

I'm new to working with Ext Js.
I downloaded it using npm and then followed the documentation on the website,
when I tried to create my first application, I got an error saying "caractere incorrect"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkLB6.png)

Did anyone encounter this issue, if yes I would like to hear how to fix it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is still stuck?
check one of these commands, they helped.

sencha app init --ext@7.3.0.55 --modern Youtube

sencha generate app --ext@7.3.0.55 Youtube C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test